# Прячется клавиатура при клике на input

Tags: javascript, html, input, responsive, mobile-web

[Страница товара](http://kilimanjaro.com.ua/shop/product/velosiped-16-formula-fitness-14g-st-belo-oranzhevyi-2015)

При покупке в кредит с телефона невозможно заполнить поля. Клавиатура выползает и сразу прячется.[image: Форма для покупки]

Comment: Может потому что в кредит?

Comment: нет, не вариант )